# Laravel middleware auth redirect

Tags: laravel, redirect, middleware

I have inside my `LoginController`:

```
protected $redirectTo = '/landlords/dashboard';
```

which works great when i `post data` to the `login endpoint`.

When I add this piece of code to my `routes`

```
Route::group(array('middleware' => 'auth:api'), function(){
   // other routes here including landlords/dashboard
})
```

It overrides the `$redirectTo` and sends to `/home` when i log in.

Comment: This might be due to your `RedirectIfAuthenticated` middleware. This has a default redirect path to `/home` [Source](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php#L21). Also, why are you grouping your web routes under api?

Comment: @adam changing the groups to auth middleware solved it

Comment: @adam everything is implemented correctly. my next question is if they are not authenticated and try to access a protected page it sends them to the `login` endpoint. i need to change that endpoint somewhere else

Comment: Check the authenticate [middleware](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php). Or define your `login` route as the path you want.